# Questions About Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I am new to thread programing and I have a conceptual problem.  I am doing matrix multiplication as a project for my class.  However, I do it without using threads, and then using threads to compute the scalar product for each cell of the answer matrix, and then once again splitting up the first matrix into proportions so that each thread has a equal portion to compute.  My problem is that the scalar product implementation finishes very quickly which is what I expect, but the third implementation doesn't computer the answer much faster than the nonthreaded implementation.  For instance, if it were to use 2 threads, it would copute it in roughly half the time because it can work on both halves of the matrix at the same time but that is not the case at all.  I feel like there is an issue in the  third implementation, I don't think it operates in parallel, the code is below.  Can anyone set me straight on this? Not all of the code is relevant to the question but I included it in case the problem is not local.
Thanks,

Main Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

#include <matrix.h>
#include <timer.h>
#include <random_generator2.h>

const float averager=2.0; //used to find the average of the time taken to multiply the matrices.

//Precondition: The matrix has been manipulated in some way and is ready to output the statistics
//Outputs the size of the matrix along with the user elapsed time.
//Postconidition: The stats are outputted to the file that is specified with the number of threads used
//file name example: "Nonparrallel2.dat"
void output(string file, int numThreads , long double time, int n);

//argv[1] = the size of the matrix
//argv[2] = the number of threads to be used.
//argv[3] = 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
  random_generator rg;
  timer t, nonparallel, scalar, variant;
  int n, total = 0, numThreads = 0;
  long double totalNonP = 0, totalScalar = 0, totalVar = 0;

  n = 100;

/*
 * check arguments
 */
      n = atoi(argv[1]);
      n = (n < 1) ? 1 : n;
      numThreads = atoi(argv[2]);
/*
 * allocated and generate random strings
 */
  int** C;
  int** A;
  int** B;

  cout << "**NOW STARTING ANALYSIS FOR " << n << " X " << n << " MATRICES WITH " << numThreads << "!**"<< endl;

  for (int timesThrough = 0; timesThrough < averager; timesThrough++)
  {

      cout << "Creating the matrices." << endl;
      t.start();
      C = create_matrix(n);
      A = create_random_matrix(n, rg);
      B = create_random_matrix(n, rg);
      t.stop();

      cout << "Timer (generate): " << t << endl;

        //---------------------------------------------------------Ends non parallel-----------------------------
        /*
         * run algorithms
         */
          cout << "Running non-parallel matrix multiplication: " << endl;
          nonparallel.start();
          multiply(C, A, B, n);
          nonparallel.stop();
        //-----------------------------------------Ends non parallel----------------------------------------------


        //cout << "The correct matrix" <<endl;
        //output_matrix(C, n);

          cout << "Timer (multiplication): " << nonparallel << endl;
          totalNonP += nonparallel.user();


          //D is the transpose of B so that the p_scalarproduct function does not have to be rewritten
          int** D = create_matrix(n); 
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                D[i][j] = B[j][i];
        //---------------------------------------------------Start Threaded Scalar Poduct--------------------------
          cout << "Running scalar product in parallel" << endl;
          scalar.start();
          //Does the scalar product in parallel to multiply the two matrices.
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            C[i][j] = 0;
            C[i][j] = p_scalarproduct(A[i],D[j],n,numThreads);
            }//ends the for loop with j
          scalar.stop();

          cout << "Timer (scalar product in parallel): " << scalar << endl;
          totalScalar += scalar.user();
        //---------------------------------------------------Ends Threaded Scalar Poduct------------------------


        //---------------------------------------------------Starts Threaded Variant For Loop---------------
           cout << "Running the variation on the for loop." << endl;
            boost :: thread** thrds;


            //create threads and bind to p_variantforloop_t
            thrds = new boost::thread*[numThreads];

            variant.start();
            for (int i = 1; i <= numThreads; i++)
                thrds[i-1] = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&p_variantforloop_t, 
                        C, A, B, ((i)*n - n)/numThreads ,(i * n)/numThreads, numThreads, n));   
cout << "before join" <<endl;
            // join threads 
              for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            thrds[i]->join();
             variant.stop();

            // cleanup 
              for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            delete thrds[i];
              delete[] thrds;

        cout << "Timer (variation of for loop): " << variant <<endl;
        totalVar += variant.user();
        //---------------------------------------------------Ends Threaded Variant For Loop------------------------

         // output_matrix(A, n);
         // output_matrix(B, n);
         //   output_matrix(E,n);

        /*
         * free allocated storage
         */

        cout << "Deleting Storage" <<endl;

          delete_matrix(A, n);
          delete_matrix(B, n);
          delete_matrix(C, n);
          delete_matrix(D, n);  

        //avoids dangling pointers
          A = NULL;
          B = NULL;
          C = NULL;
          D = NULL;
  }//ends the timesThrough for loop   

  //output the results to .dat files
  output("Nonparallel", numThreads, (totalNonP / averager) , n);
  output("Scalar", numThreads, (totalScalar / averager), n);
  output("Variant", numThreads, (totalVar / averager), n);

  cout << "Nonparallel = " << (totalNonP / averager) << endl;
  cout << "Scalar = " << (totalScalar / averager) << endl;
  cout << "Variant = " << (totalVar / averager) << endl;

  return 0;
}

void output(string file, int numThreads , long double time, int n)
{
    ofstream dataFile;
    stringstream ss;

    ss << numThreads;
    file += ss.str();
    file += ".dat";

    dataFile.open(file.c_str(), ios::app);
    if(dataFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "The output file didn't open." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }//ends the if statement.
    dataFile << n << "     " << time << endl;
    dataFile.close();
}//ends optimalOutput function
```

Matrix file:

```
#include <matrix.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int** create_matrix(int n)
{
  int** matrix;

  if (n < 1) 
    return 0;

  matrix = new int*[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[n];

  return matrix;
}

int** create_random_matrix(int n, random_generator& rg)
{
  int** matrix;

  if (n < 1) 
    return 0;

  matrix = new int*[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      matrix[i] = new int[n];
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    //rg >> matrix[i][j];
    matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
    }

  return matrix;
}

void delete_matrix(int** matrix, int n)
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
      delete[] matrix[i];

    delete[] matrix;

    //avoids dangling pointers.
    matrix = NULL;
}

/*
 * non-parallel matrix multiplication
 */
void multiply(int** C, int** A, int** B, int n)
{ 
  if ((C == A) || (C == B))
    { 
      cout << "ERROR: C equals A or B!" << endl;
      return;
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      {
    C[i][j] = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
      C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
     }
} 

void p_scalarproduct_t(int* c, int* a, int* b, 
                   int s, int e, boost::mutex* lock)
{ 
  int tmp;

  tmp = 0;
  for (int k = s; k < e; k++){
    tmp += a[k] * b[k];
//cout << "a[k]= "<<a[k]<<"b[k]= "<< b[k] <<"    "<<k<<endl;
}
  lock->lock();
  *c = *c + tmp;
  lock->unlock();
} 

int p_scalarproduct(int* a, int* b, int n, int m)
{ 
  int c;
  boost::mutex lock;
  boost::thread** thrds;

  c = 0;

/* create threads and bind to p_merge_sort_t */
  thrds = new boost::thread*[m];
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    thrds[i] = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&p_scalarproduct_t, 
                             &c, a, b, i*n/m, (i+1)*n/m, &lock));
/* join threads */
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    thrds[i]->join();

/* cleanup */
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    delete thrds[i];
  delete[] thrds;

  return c;
} 

void output_matrix(int** matrix, int n)
{ 
  cout << "[";
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      cout << "[ ";
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
      cout << "]" << endl;
    }
  cout << "]" << endl;
}





void p_variantforloop_t(int** C, int** A, int** B, int s, int e, int numThreads, int n)
{
//cout << "s= " <<s<<endl<< "e= " << e << endl;
    for(int i = s; i < e; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
          C[i][j] = 0;
//cout << "i " << i << "  j " << j << endl;
          for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
            C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];}
        }
}//ends the function
```

Comment: If you isolate and run just the third variation, do you see all your CPU cores simultaneously active (and hopefully pegged)? ... It seems from the code it should be working in parallel, but that would at least give you a quick sanity check if something were wrong.

Comment: @jason I'm unsure how to check this with Linux, do you have any suggestions on how to do this? I am using a computer at school so I dont have root privileges.

Comment: What distro?  On Ubuntu I just go to System->Administration->System Monitor to see the CPU load ... Fedora/RH/SuSE/etc. have the same thing, although the menus can be in different places.  Also if you only have a command-line at your disposal, you can type in `top` to get a process-based CPU monitor (also gives lots of other statistics).

Comment: yea that's what I did but it only had one CPU graph which doesn't make sense to me at all because the other threaded implementation actually computes in parallel...and yes I am running Ubuntu

Comment: BTW, `top` is interactive, so if you press the 'h' key, you'll get a bunch of helpful commands to show you how to manipulate what you see in the main display.  For instance, '<' and '>' will scroll among the processes, pressing 'u' will prompt you for a user to filter processes for, and pressing '1' will give you a SMP view of your CPU's.  Finally by pressing 'd' you can change the update speed (1.0 is one second, but it can be less than that).

Comment: There is one CPU graph, but it should have a bunch of different colored lines on it to represent the different CPU's ... you want to see all the CPU's pegged up at the top, not one color at the top, and the rest at the bottom.  Also along the bottom of the graph you should see the CPU usage percentages that let you know how much of each CPU is being used.  For something like your algorithm, they should be pretty near or at 100% while working on your problem.

Comment: well then I have only one CPU because there is only an orange line...So how come one threaded implementation works correctly but the other one is badly off

Comment: There's an overhead for using threads ... you have to start and stop them, initialize some stack space for each thread, copy states, etc., etc.  If you're launching a bunch of threads that only do a very simple task, then often times you'll see more time being spend setting up and destroying a thread than actually doing computations.  On Linux, boost::threads is a wrapper around Linux's native pthreads, so I'm not sure how the threads are being launched (i.e., what the values in the fields of `pthread_attr_t` are).  What happens when you setup a VERY LARGE matrix (i.e, 500x500)?

Comment: I've only been using very large matrices like 1750X1750...so its the same problem

Comment: Based on the fact you're only using a single CPU system (how odd is that nowadays ... it must be virtualized or something of that sort), I've given a new answer on what I think the issue might be (I don't think it has anything to-do with threads).

Comment: Just curious, where you able to find out or confirm anything else about the performance disparity?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're running into [False Sharing](http://drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=217500206). Try to use a local variable in `p_variantforloop_t`:

```
void p_variantforloop_t(int** C, int** A, int** B, int s, int e, int numThreads, int n)
{
    for(int i = s; i < e; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
          int accu = 0;
          for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            accu += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
          C[i][j] = accu;
        }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me but when I add that to my program, it is not reflected in my output at all, even though I added exactly what was in that article

Comment: What happens if you had a whole temporary matrix as an accumulator in your function, and only copied the results from the temporary matrix to C at the very end of the `p_variantforloop_t` function rather than copying cell-by-cell in the middle of the for-loops?

Comment: @Jason: I was thinking the same, but OP's dividing work along the maximum-stride dimension (first index, correct?) and the writes go along the minimum-stride dimension, so I'm not so sure anymore it's actually False Sharing, unless the extents are _very_ small.

Comment: Another possible explanation would be that the program is limited by bandwidth between the CPU and RAM... in which case dividing the task up across multiple cores can't really help, as now he just has two cores waiting for RAM reads/writes to complete, instead of one.

Comment: But then why is only one implementation affected and not the other parallel one?

Comment: Rather than waiting for your threads to join, have you thought about setting them as detachable by calling `detatch()` and simply updating a shared variable (guard it via an atomic operation or mutex) in each thread that will be used as a semaphore to tell the main thread to continue (i.e., in the main thread if the variable == 2, then it's time to continue since that means both threads have finished their job)?  I'm wondering if something is happening in the wait for the threads to join that is throwing off your timers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your responses in the comments, in theory, because you only have a single thread (i.e., CPU) available, all the threaded versions should be the same time as the single-threaded version or longer because of thread management overhead.  You shouldn't be seeing any speedup at all since the time slice-taken to solve one part of the matrix is a time-slice that is stolen from another parallel task.  With a single CPU you're only time-sharing the CPU's resources--there is no real parallel working going on in a given single slice of time.  I would suspect then the reason your second implementation runs faster is because you're doing less pointer dereferencing and memory access in your inner loop.  For example, in the main operation `C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];` from both `multiply` and `p_variantforloop_t`, you're looking at a lot of operations at the assembly level, many of them memory related.  It would look something like the following in "assembly pseudo-code":

1) Move pointer value from address referenced by `A` on the stack into register `R1`
2) Increment the address in register `R1` by the value off the stack referenced by the variable `i`, `j`, or `k`
3) Move the pointer address value from the address pointed to by `R1` into `R1`
4) Increment the address in `R1` by the value off the stack referenced by the variable `i`, `j`, or `k`
5) Move the value from the address pointed to by `R1` into `R1` (so `R1` now holds the value of `A[i][k]`)
6) Do steps 1-5 for the address referenced by `B` on the stack into register `R2` (so `R2` now holds the value of `B[k][j]`)
7) Do steps 1-4 for the address referenced by `C` on the stack into register `R3`
8) Move the value from the address pointed to by `R3` into `R4` (i.e., `R4` holds the actual value at `C[i][j]`)
9) Multiply registers `R1` and `R2` and store in register `R5`
10) Add registers `R4` and `R5` and store in `R4`
11) Move the final value from `R4` back into the memory address pointed to by `R3` (now `C[i][j]` has the final result)

And that's assuming we have 5 general purpose registers to play with, and the compiler properly optimized your C-code to take advantage of them.  I left the loop index variables `i`, `j`, and `k` on the stack, so accessing those will take even more time than if they were in registers ... it really depends on how many registers your compiler has to play with on your platform.  Additionally, if you compiled without any optimizations, you could be doing a lot more memory access off the stack, where some of these temp values are stored on the stack rather than in registers, and then reaccessed off the stack, which takes a lot longer than moving values between registers.  Either way, the code above is a lot harder to optimize.  It works, but if you're on a 32-bit x86 platform, then you're not going to have that many general purpose registers to play with (you should have at least 6 though).  x86_64 has more registers to play with, but still, there are all the memory accesses to contend with.

On the other-hand an operation like `tmp += a[k] * b[k]` from `p_scalarproduct_t` in a tight inner loop is going to move MUCH faster ... here is the above operation in assembly pseudo-code:

There would be a small initialization step for the loop

1) Make `tmp` a register `R1` rather than stack variable, and initialize it's value to 0
2) Move the address value referenced by `a` on the stack into `R2`
3) Add the value of `s` off the stack to `R2` and save resulting address in `R2`
4) Move the address value referenced by `b` on the stack into `R3`
5) Add the value of `s` off the stack to `R3` and save resulting address in `R3`
6) Setup a counter in `R6` initialized to `e - s`

After the one-time initialization we would begin the actual inner loop

7) Move the value from the address pointed to by `R2` into `R4`
8) Move the value from the address pointed to by `R3` into `R5`
9) Multiply `R4` and `R5` and store the results in `R5`
10) Add `R5` to `R1` and store the results in `R1`
11) Increment `R2` and `R3`
12) Decrement counter in `R6` until it reaches zero, where we terminate loop

I can't guarantee this is exactly how your compiler would setup this loop, but you can see in general with your scalar example there are less steps in the inner loop required, and more importantly less memory accesses.  Therefore more can be done with operations that are solely using registers rather than operations that include memory locations and require a memory fetch, which is much slower than register-only operations. So in general it's going to move a lot faster, and that has nothing to-do with threads.

Finally, I notice you only have two nested loops for the scalar product, so it's complexity is O(N^2), where-as for your other two methods you have three nested loops for O(N^3) complexity.  That's going to make a difference as well.